# foxit reader shows wrong aspect ratio, contents are vertically stretched

Tags: foxit-reader

I don't remember what I did that incurred the problem, the contents are vertically stretched, even after reinstall foxit reader of latest version, the problem persist, I'm using ubuntu 16.04. now my foxit reader shows pdf like

[image]

while the correct one should be

[image]

I have googled it and got similar reported issue:[Wrong aspect ratio on Linux version of Reader](http://%20http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/156055-wrong-aspect-ratio-on-linux-version-of-reader), but the issue was not resolved

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue while using dual monitors.

Close the app, Setting the display back and forth to a single display (Dual -> Single ->Dual) fixed the problem.

OS : Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 - the solution above still applies. 
Ergo we still have a problem here.